# Appium xpath value

Tags: ios, mobile, xpath, appium

When Im trying to inspect my app (IOS), in console I see the appium's response :

```
[{"UIAImage":{"@":{"name":"/Users/ie54553/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/123456/data/Applications/789798/My.app/Resources.bundle/black_btn.png",
  "label":null,"value":null,"dom":null,"enabled":true,"valid":true,"visible":false,
  "hint":null,"path":"/0/0/7/0","x":10,"y":264,"width":80,"height":80}
```

The path property in this case is : 0/0/7/0

While I'm looking in appium inspector , the xpath value is:

```
//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAImage[4]/UIAImage[1]
```

Any idea how does the responsed "path" being translated to the xpath value ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relationship:

- UIAImage is an array index of the JSON.
- UIAImage is a child node of the XML.

Since JavaScript is zero indexed and XPath is one indexed, here is the mapping:

```
XPath                                                   JSON
//UIAAplication[1]                                      0
//UIAAplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]                         0/0
//UIAAplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAImage[4]             0/0/7
//UIAAplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAImage[4]/UIAImage[1] 0/0/7/0
```